# Using an HTML element's ID in JavaScript returns its DOM reference

Tags: javascript

html code:

```
<div id="register"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
console.log( register );//without even declaring the variable register
```

it returns `<div id=​"register"></div>` in the console.

Is that a normal behavior? (tested in Chrome and Firefox)

Is it documented somewhere?

Is it part of the ECMAScript specification?

Comment: It's normal behavior.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I just tested IE11, and it does the same; I was unaware of this.

Comment: Microsoft [wrote](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx) of this back in 2009 ("The cause for this behaviour is that Internet Explorer creates global variables for each element of the DOM.")

Answer (score -3):

This is [DOM level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/), but doesn't wort in old IEs, IIRC.

Comment: Old versions of IE do it too. There are dozens of old questions about "why does my JavaScript work in IE but not Firefox" caused by this because old versions of *Firefox* didn't do it.

Comment: Where in DOM level 1 is this described? You've linked to the spec's homepage. The spec is rather large.